# In the Microsoft Bot Framework, how can I extract parameters from the url of the chat?

Tags: html, node.js, botframework

I wrote an html page where a user signs in (the data file is in json) and I can save his/her first name and gender. I pass them as parameters in the request's url where the bot lives.

```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    function processRequest(e) {
      var url;
      if (xhr.readyState == 4  && xhr.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        url = "https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/nodejsbot98?firstname="+firstname+"&gender="+gender+"&t="+response;
        document.getElementById("chat").src= url;
      }
    }
```

Now in the app.js, I want the bot to greet that user with the first name and based on the gender, the bot is a male or female. How does the url call the app.js to send and receive messages? How can I access those parameters from the url?

EDIT: Using the backchannel, is that script correct?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
        <script>
      var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        secret: 'TGDGNQY7JK0.cwA.XiQ.I1LDLE5qI3Jsx6q7dlnMMrJtEoLcbTdOE-QIZ4AA_1Y',
      });

var user = {
  id:  'userid',
  name: 'username'
};

var bot = {
  id:  'botid',
  name: 'botname'
};

BotChat.App({
  botConnection: botConnection,
  user: user,
  bot: bot,
}, document.getElementById("bot"));

botConnection
                    .postActivity({type: "event", value: "", from: {id: "me" }, name: "greeting", data:{firstname:'Alain', gender:'male'}})
                    .subscribe(id => console.log("success"));    
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, it's better to leverage [The Backchannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel) feature of botframework-webchat library, as the Bot service's embed web chat is difficult to pass values from url.

Leveraging the Web chat js library, you can set the value like:

```
botConnection .postActivity({ type: "event", from: user, name: "customeEvt", data:{fitstname:'Gary',gender:'Male'} }) .subscribe(activity => console.log(activity));
```

And in bot application, you can retrieve the variables via `event` triggers:

```
bot.on('event',(event) => {
  if (event.name === 'customeEvt') {
      console.log(event)// use the data as **event.data** as you set the variable as 'data'
      bot.beginDialog(event.address, '<any dialog>', event.data);//pass your value to dialog
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please check my edit to make sure I used the backchannel correctly in the htm file? Do I need to add anything else in the file or bot application? Also, do I access the user's data (username + gender) with event.data[0] and [1]?

Comment: Yes, you need to register your event in bot application as my second code snippet. And the the `data` parameter in `postActivity` object, is defined by yourself, you can set anyother parameter name, e.g. if you set `value`, then you use `event.value` in bot application. As you set an object to `data`, so you get an object in bot not an array. So `event.data` shuold be `Object{fitstname:'Gary',gender:'Male'}` not an array here. Of cause you can send Array to bot via backchannel  as well.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do I need to fire the customeEvt or postbuttonmessage somehow or is it automatic once the bot is connected? With my code above, I get a console error that BotChat is undefined, and there's a use before declaration of postButtonMessage if I try to call it from a button. The syntax "const postButtonMessage = () => {" is weird

Comment: Yes, it's automatic once the bot webchat connected. And for your issue, it likely you miss the js library included in your html page. please look carefully at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline

Comment: I used     <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
but I am getting an error "FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. (XHR): POST - https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations". The app secret works on https://botchattest.herokuapp.com/ so I guess something is wrong with the code. Also if it might help I'm also getting another error "Unable to set property 'src' of undefined or null reference" at this line: document.getElementById("chat").src= url; (chat is the id of iframe)

Comment: Could you ues the code sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline first? As when you are using the js library, there is no necessary to set the iframe url manually.

Comment: Okay I did now (look at updated code). I can see the event name and data etc on the app.js side in the console so that works. But I am having a "Error: Dialog[*:<any dialog>] not found.".

Comment: Hey man, the `'<any dialog>'` in my code snippet is onlt kinda of placeholder, you nned to change to your own dialog name in your bot application! E.G. you set `bot.beginDialog(event.address, 'test', event);` in event, then you can define the dialog as `bot.dialog('test', [
  (session, args) => {
    session.send(`${JSON.stringify(args.data) }`)
  }
])
`